# $\ell^2$ operator given by sum of neighbors

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T : \ell^2(\mathbb Z^d) \to \ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)$ be given by $Tx_n = \sum_{\vert n - j \vert = 1} x_j$. What is the spectrum of this operator? I think it would help to reduce it to multiplication operator under a unitary and then we can use the fact that the spectrum will just be the essential range of the multiplying function.

I think this may be related to the $n$-dimensional Fourier transform but I'm struggling to see the relation. My guess is that the map $\{c_n\} \to \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z^d} \vert c_n\vert^2 e^{inx}$ may be useful, but I can't really get far with this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}^d$ has a group structure via pointwise operations. Under this group structure $T$ is convolution by $\sum_{|n| = 1} \delta_n$. Since the dual of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the circle group $\mathbb{T}$, by performing a Fourier transform we have $T$ is conjugate to the multiplication operator $L^2(\mathbb{T}^d) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)$ given by,

$$UTU^*(f) = \sum_{i = 1}^d (z_if + \bar{z_i}f) = 2\sum_{i = 1}^d \textrm{Re}(z_i)f$$

The essential range of multiplication by $\textrm{Re}(z_i)$ is $[-1, 1]$, as $z_i$ ranges over $\mathbb{T}$. Since each $z_i$ acts on different tensor components, we thus have the essential range of $UTU^*$ is given by 2 times the sum of essential ranges of all $\textrm{Re}(z_i)$, i.e., $[-2d, 2d]$. Hence, the spectrum of $T$ is $[-2d, 2d]$ as well.

Comment: @Eulerian $\delta_n$ is just the standard basis element that evaluates to 1 at $n$ and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: @Eulerian I’m using a generalized version of Fourier transform that applies to all locally compact abelian groups. If you want to be concrete though, $U$ is given by $U((c_n)) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d} c_n \prod_{i = 1}^d z_i^{n_i} \in L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)$. (I’m using the normalized arc length measure on $\mathbb{T}$ here. If you prefer the regular arc length measure, multiply the above by the normalization constant $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}$.)